# Eclipse code line change

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I often switch from Eclipse to Netbeans and back. There is a feature in Netbeans that allows you to see changed lines in code due to repository.

Example:
 [image]

Is there something similar in Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, right click the file `Team` -> `Show Annotation...` When you hover over the colored line numbers you see the committing user and the commit message. If it is a local change it is just white.

[image: Annotations]

Comment: but, i think that Netbeans' tool is better in usage:(